# Sum of the digits of $99^{99}$?

Tags: divisibility

I have been looking at this for quite a while, however I can't find a solution - I guess there needs to be a clever way to deal with this incredibly large number that I am not aware of...
I actually need to figure out **the digit sum of the digit sum of the digit sum of 99⁹⁹**. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is divisible by 9, so the digit sum is 9 ?

Comment: Well, the digit sum can be any multiple of 9...

Comment: @ganeshie8 The OP says that he wants to compute the digit sum $3$ times, not indefinitely.

Comment: Ah ok. Then I'd start by figuring out the `max` number of digits in the digit sum of $99^{99}$

Comment: @rogerl Clever!

Comment: I get $\operatorname{digsum}(99^n)=\begin{cases}9(n+1),&n\ \text{odd}\\9n,&n\ \text{even}\end{cases}$ but haven't yet proven it.

Comment: You can take the number mod 100 since 99=-1. The digit sum of digit sum of digit sum will not be more than 100.

Comment: $99^{99}$ has $\lfloor 99 \log_{10} 99 + 1 \rfloor = 198$ digits, and the maximum sum (if they are all $9$s) is $198 \cdot 9$. It should not be hard to prove that for any four digit number, the sum reduces to $9$ in three steps, since finding the digit sum takes at least one digit from the number.

Comment: FYI: the sum of digits of $99^{99}$ is $936$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$99^{99}$ is less than $10^{198}$, therefore has at most 198 digits. 
When you sum them up (first time), you get a number that is less than or equal to $9\times 198=1782$. 
When you sum up the digits of that number (second time), you get something less than or equal to $\max(9+9+9, 1+6+9+9)=27$.
When you sum up the digits of this last number, you get something less than or equal to $\max(2+7, 1+9)=10$.

But the original number is a multiple of $9$, hence the last number has to be a multiple of $9$. Note that it cannot be zero, because only $0$ itself has a sum of digits equal to $0$ and you started from $99^{99}\neq 0$. Therefore it is $9$.

Comment: Actually $99^{99}$ has $198$ digits since $10^{198}$ has $199$ digits, but your idea still works.

Comment: The digit sum is 936. The digital root is 9.

Comment: @TobyMak True! $10^n$ has $n+1$ digits. Bedtime over here :)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This makes total sense and is actually very simple but I would have never thought of just trying this...

Comment: @TonyStarck You're very welcome.

Answer (score 4):

$$99^{99}<100^{100}=10^{200}$$ so $99^{99}$ has at most $200$ digits and its digit sum is at most $1800.$  The digit sum of the digit sum is at most $28$ (a $1$ and three $9$'s).  The digit sum of the digit sum of the digit sum is at most $11$, and it must be divisible by $9$, so it can only be $9$.